Server not responding to ICMP requests
I have 4 servers running on rocky linux at a datacenter in Chicago but one is not answering to ping requests. I have been checking for solutions for day but so far things look good, what I am missing?
[(01:51 PM)][(root@server)] [(~)] $ ip r
default via 208.117.37.129 dev enp68s0f0 proto static metric 100
208.117.37.129 dev enp68s0f0 proto static scope link metric 100 

[(01:56 PM)][(root@server)] [(~)] $ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp68s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 208.117.*.*/32 scope global noprefixroute enp68s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7ec2:55ff:fe23:cd3c/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp68s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp68s0f2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp68s0f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    
[(01:58 PM)][(root@server)] [(~)] $ ifconfig
enp68s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 208.117.*.*  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::7ec2:55ff:fe23:cd3c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 520286825  bytes 181418408778 (168.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 703930349  bytes 873242718055 (813.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp68s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 165  bytes 10362 (10.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp68s0f2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        
[(01:59 PM)][(root@server)] [(~)] $ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         208.117.37.129  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp68s0f0
208.117.37.129  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 enp68s0f0

[(01:59 PM)][(root@server)] [(~)] $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp68s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 208.117.*.*/32 scope global noprefixroute enp68s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7ec2:55ff:fe23:cd3c/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp68s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp68s0f2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp68s0f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:c2:55:23:cd:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff        

[(02:00 PM)][(root@server)] [(~)] $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
0


(as root) nft list ruleset?

It's not clear if 1/ your question is about your server having a connectivity issue, ie: routing issue or 2/ it's only about ICMP not working. You should clarify what works and what doesn't work, and provide a comparision with one of the working servers. Also, please avoid obfuscating using wildcard in IP addresses, some people might not understand what it means. I suggest instead replacing with addresses from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737.html#section-3 chosen carefully to not alter the problem.
